# Visual basic for excel or VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My question
To generate an email in outlook for the cell whose description is blank. the email should be sent to the respective person whose cell is blank.

PS: this is not a fixed order, blanks can be anywhere so i am looking for a loop which runs n number of times and produces an email as soon as it encounters a blank and still checks for other blanks.

Ps: the number of rows is also not pre defined. it can be 4 or 5 or 50 as well.

revert quickly please

Comment: What did you try yet?

Comment: You've not given anywhere near enough information on this, nor told us what you have tried that hasn't been successful.  SO is not a site where you ask for code to be written for you, and certainly not by demanding that it is done quickly..

Comment: Welcome to SO @Dharwal Kumar Jain!  Please review the [how to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidelines on composing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Excel.UserRange, loop through the rows and access the cells by ThisWorkBook.Sheets(1).Cells(row, col).Value. If you find the value to be null or nothing or empty string, then call your sending mail function